# Get nested item from XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I've looked at some examples on the web but I am still struggling with this. 
I would like to get the value for "**descShort**" tag within the "**indexDesc**" tag and then after that display the value from the "**last**" tag? I've seen people using the arrow > but I'm still lost.

```
<indices>
    <index>
        <code>DJI</code>
        <exchange>NYSE</exchange>
        <liveness>DELAYED</liveness>
        <indexDesc>
            <desc>Dow Jones Industrials</desc>
            <descAbbrev>DOW JONES</descAbbrev>
            <descShort>DOW JONES</descShort>
            <firstActive></firstActive>
            <lastActive></lastActive>
        </indexDesc>
        <indexQuote>
            <capital>
                <first>11144.57</first>
                <high>11153.79</high>
                <low>10973.92</low>
                <last>11018.66</last>
                <change>-125.9</change>
                <pctChange>-1.1%</pctChange>
            </capital>
            <gross>
                <first>11144.57</first>
                <high>11153.79</high>
                <low>10973.92</low>
                <last>11018.66</last>
                <change>-125.9</change>
                <pctChange>-1.1%</pctChange>
            </gross>
            <totalEvents>4</totalEvents>
            <lastChanged>16-Apr-2010 16:03:00</lastChanged>
        </indexQuote>
    </index>
    <index>
        <code>XAO</code>
        <exchange>ASX</exchange>
        <liveness>DELAYED</liveness>
        <indexDesc>
            <desc>ASX All Ordinaries</desc>
            <descAbbrev>All Ordinaries</descAbbrev>
            <descShort>ALL ORDS</descShort>
            <firstActive>06-Mar-1970</firstActive>
            <lastActive></lastActive>
        </indexDesc>
        <indexQuote>
            <capital>
                <first>5007.30</first>
                <high>5007.30</high>
                <low>4934.00</low>
                <last>4939.40</last>
                <change>-67.9</change>
                <pctChange>-1.4%</pctChange>
            </capital>
            <gross>
                <first>5007.30</first>
                <high>5007.30</high>
                <low>4934.00</low>
                <last>4939.40</last>
                <change>-67.9</change>
                <pctChange>-1.4%</pctChange>
            </gross>
            <totalEvents>997</totalEvents>
            <lastChanged>19-Apr-2010 17:02:54</lastChanged>
        </indexQuote>
    </index>
</indices>
```

Comment: You have to describe it better. There are more than one `last` tag and how do you want the output to be like? Can you provide an example?

Comment: sorry, I would like just the "last" value from "gross" parent tag along with the previous shortDesc

Answer (score 1):

The ">" is a selector; you can see all f the available ones here: [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors). "div > span" will find all spans that have div's as parents. This is different to "div span", which will find all spans which are descendents of divs.

```
var values = [];

$(yourXml).find('index').each(function () {
  var self = $(this);

  values.push({
    descShort: self.find('descShort:first').text(),
    capitalLast: self.children('capital').children('last').text(),
    grossLast: self.children('gross').children('last').text()
  });
});
```

`values` is now an array of objects, each with descShort, captialLast and grossLast properties.

Unfortunately I can't test my code.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the values are coming up empty for some reason. it keeps saying 'undefined' when i trt print the value. ie

alert(self.find('descShort:first').val());

Comment: Try .text() or .html() instead. Not sure why I used .val() in the first place tbh :)