# Select div inside div not its child div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following XML file -

```
<section>
  <qus>
    <text>A</text>
    <ans>
      <text>B</text>
      <qus>
        <text>C</text>
        <qus>
          <text>E</text>
        </qus>
      </qus>
      <qus>
        <text>D</text>
      </qus>
    </ans>
  </qus>
</section>
```

I need to select `qus > ans > qus` text and sibling `qus`, but not the `qus` inside that.

I need  result text **C** & **D** not `E`
How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Can you even run jQuery over an XML file?

Comment: The selector would be exactly what you've put in the question: `$("qus>ans>qus")` if you can have sub-sub-answers, then maybe add section: `$("section>qus>ans>qus")`

Comment: @JamesKraus yes i run jquery over xml

Comment: @JamesKraus yes, you just parse it and then run your jQuery functions in it

Comment: @freedomn-m i have use this but its select child also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read xml file contents in jQuery and display in html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements)

Comment: @kevinb. i need perfect selector and i know how to read xml and work over it

Comment: Could you try `.find('qus ans qus').text();`, following the answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2674623/5178016)? Or does it still select the children as well?

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MogjRP

Comment: If it's getting the children, you're doing something wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/e6m9qnfo/  (section>qus doesn't work in the fiddle as it's not fully parsed, so section is not part of document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this selector. See if it is what you need.

```js
$(function() {
  var xml = "<section><qus><text>A</text><ans><text>B</text><qus><text>C</text><qus><text>E</text></qus></qus><qus><text>D</text></qus></ans></qus></section>";
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
  var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

  var $el = $xml.find('section > qus > ans > qus > text');

  if ($el.length > 0) {
    $el.each(function() {
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```